# Sql group by like feature with awk

Tags: unix, awk

How to display below result group by below 50%, below 80%, 80-90%, above 90%

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0       18G   15G  2.5G  86% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            483M  4.0K  483M   1% /dev
tmpfs            99M  1.4M   97M   2% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            492M  1.8M  490M   1% /run/shm
none            100M   20K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda3       167G  157G  9.9G  95% /host
```

till now I am able fetch mount point & space using awk

```
df -hk | awk '{print $5 " " $6}'
```

**expected:**

```
0-50%: 7
80-90%: 1
90-100%: 1
```

Comment: What have you tried that would actually group the results? Your existing awk script obviously doesn't try to do that.  At the very least, please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36369456/edit) to demonstrate what you're aiming for in pseudo-code and we can help you translate it into awk.

Comment: Note that the `awk` script you show gives the 'Avail' and 'Use%' columns; it doesn't give the mount point (which is `$6`).

Comment: Please edit your question to show the expected output given that input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -v groups='50 80 90 100' '
          BEGIN{n=split(groups,g);g[0]=0}
               {sub("%","",$5);
                for(i=1;i<=n;i++) 
                   if($5+0<=g[i]) {a[g[i-1]"-"g[i]]++; next}
               } 
            END{for(k in a) print "between: "k"%:",a[k]}' file | 
  sort -k2n

between: 0-50%: 7
between: 80-90%: 1
between: 90-100%: 1
```